# Control an swf file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an swf file embedded into my webpage and I want to control it. I know that the controls are not available for an swf file, so I'm controlling it using JavaScript. I've managed get a Play and Pause button, but I really need to Stop button which will Stop the movie and rewind it to the beginning.

```
    <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="javascript:document.movie.Play()">►</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">║</a>
```

This is code I'm using so far. I'm using ASCII codes to get the Play and Pause symbol and I can easily get a stop one but is there a way I can Stop and reset the movie?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this works, if the Flash movie has hooks for Javascript:

This answer has more information:

[Possible to control SWF through Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658751/possible-to-control-swf-through-javascript)

Comment: I've found a solution. You can set the file to go to a specific frame so I set it to go back to frame one. This also stops it so it works like a stop button. It means if it combined we a play command, it could also be used as a reset button.javascript:document.movie.GotoFrame(1)

Comment: Good find; it would benefit this community if you post that as an answer to your own question; future users can then search and find the benefit of your discovery!